# Condition to choose which getConstructor method

Tags: java

I have a class in which i have intialized hashmap in static block. Passing the key, I have retrived the value which is a class. In order to create object for this class. I have used the constructor class to get the constructor and passed arguments and created object.

I have two class in hashmap. To create objectfor EchoExpression I need to pass two arguments and for OutExpression class i need to pass only one argument(String).

Question:

Based on the class returned by the key I need to execute which constructor to get and implement, whether the constructor with one argument or two argument.

```
public class ExampleFactory {

  private static HashMap<String,Class<?>> hmap = new HashMap<String,Class<?>>();

  static
  {                   
      hmap.put("echo", EchoExpression.class);         
      hmap.put("Out", OutExpression.class);                       
  }

  public void getExpo(String key,String expression)
  {
    Class aClass =map.get(key);

    //Constructor implementation for OutExpression where only one argument string is passed

    Constructor constructor = aClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class});

    Object object= constructor.newInstance(expression);

    //constructor for passing two arguments string for EchoExpression

    Constructor constructor = aClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class,Class.class});

    Object object= constructor.newInstance(expression, Boolean.class);


    return null;        
  }                
}
```

How to choose from the value(class) which class to implement without using if else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Enum and switch on it. Here is a executable stub without getting too deeply into the reflection or the syntax of your example:

```
package com.trip.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ExampleFactory {

    private static Map<String, Class<?>> hmap = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

    static {
        hmap.put("echo", EchoExpression.class);
        hmap.put("Out", OutExpression.class);
    }

    public static void getExpo(String key, String expression) {

        Class aClass = hmap.get(key);

        ClassMappingEnum myType = ClassMappingEnum.getClassMappingEnum(aClass);

        switch (myType) {
        case ECHO_EXPRESSION:{
            System.out.println(aClass.getName());
            // do something
            break;
        }
        case OUT_EXPRESSION:{
            System.out.println(aClass.getName());
            // do something
            break;          
        }
        case UNKNOWN:
        default:
            System.out.println("Bummer: " + aClass.getName());          
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getExpo("echo", "B");
        getExpo("Out", "B");
    }   
}

enum ClassMappingEnum {
    ECHO_EXPRESSION(EchoExpression.class), OUT_EXPRESSION(OutExpression.class), UNKNOWN(null);

    private Class typeDes;

    private ClassMappingEnum(Class typeDes) {
        this.typeDes = typeDes;
    }

    public static ClassMappingEnum getClassMappingEnum(Class compare) {
        for (ClassMappingEnum cme : ClassMappingEnum.values()) {
            if (cme.typeDes.equals(compare)) {
                return cme;
            }
        }
        return UNKNOWN;
    }


}

class EchoExpression<T> {
    private String someString;
    private Class<T> someClass;
    public EchoExpression(String someString, Class<T> someClass) {
        super();
        this.someString = someString;
        this.someClass = someClass;
    }
    public String getSomeString() {
        return someString;
    }
    public void setSomeString(String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }
    public Class<T> getSomeClass() {
        return someClass;
    }
    public void setSomeClass(Class<T> someClass) {
        this.someClass = someClass;
    }


}

class OutExpression {
    private String someString;

    public OutExpression(String someString) {
        super();
        this.someString = someString;
    }

    public String getSomeString() {
        return someString;
    }

    public void setSomeString(String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the classes so both constructor has the same signature (accepts the same number/type of arguments in the same order), you could do

```
Constructor constructor = aClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class,Class.class});
Object object= constructor.newInstance(expression, Boolean.class);
```

for both classes.

This of course means that the class that right now do not need the extra parameter, will have to ignore the passed-in one it was not using before after the change

UPDATE:  Here is a possible way of implementing the idea using Factory classes:

```
public interface ObjectFactory
{
  Object create(String expr, Class cls);
}

public class EchoExpressionFactory implements ObjectFactory
{
  public EchoExpression create(String expr, Class cls)
  {
    return new EchoExpression(expr, cls);
  }
}

public class OutExpressionFactory implements ObjectFactory
{
  public OutExpression create(String expr, Class cls)
  {
    return new OutExpression(expr);
  }
}

public class ExampleFactory { 

  private static HashMap<String,ObjectFactory> hmap = new HashMap<String,ObjectFactory>(); 

  static 
  {                    
      hmap.put("echo", new EchoExpressionFactory());          
      hmap.put("Out", new OutExpressionFactory());                        
  } 

  public void getExpo(String key,String expression) 
  { 
    ObjectFactory factory = map.get(key); 

    //Constructor implementation for Expression
    Object object = factory.create(expression); 

    Object object= constructor.newInstance(expression, Boolean.class); 

    return;
  }                 
}
```

Comment: I cant modify the classes since its a jar file class

Comment: Then your best bet is with `if` and `instanceof`.  If you _really_ want to avoid `if`, you could use/store factory classes that create the actual objects you want and have a common create method with all the required parameters -- you would essentially end up doing what I suggested above, but with the factory classes instead

Comment: Also, how about accepting one of the answers at [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018565/how-to-access-object-inside-static-block/), since you ended up using what was suggested?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you explain me in detail about factory class and also instance of. with some examples